# What are those broken /webstore/detail/** and /track_install/search/** URLs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I recently published a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mixcloud-downloader/mebkekakcnabgndiakbbefcgpedlaidp) ([Source Code](https://github.com/mixcloud-downloader/mixcloud-downloader-chrome-extension)) and now discover some broken incoming links on the extension's website which must be related to that extension:

- /track_install/search/ext/free/mebkekakcnabgndiakbbefcgpedlaidp/mixcloud_downloader
- /webstore/detail/ext/free/mebkekakcnabgndiakbbefcgpedlaidp/mixcloud_downloader

On the chrome extension webstore I don't find such links. Do you have any idea where those links come from and what's their purpose? Would users exepect anything else than a 404 on that URLs?

The website is referenced in the extension's manifest `homepage_url` field and on the webstore item in the "Websites" field.

**Update:** I just noticed again one such request where the referer comes from this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "incoming links"?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I notice those URLs in the webserver log of my extension's website. The website is in the manifest's `homepage_url` field plus I set it in the webstore item's "Websites" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, those URLs are relative to the Webstore and are used for Analytics tracking and [this stat page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/stats/mebkekakcnabgndiakbbefcgpedlaidp) (only available to you). See [this mention](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113036), for example.

`/track_install/...` is, quite obviously, used as a beacon to track installs.

`/webstore/detail/ext/free/...` tracks opening your extension's listing in Web Store.

Here's [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/homepage_url) on `homepage_url`, which I believe influenced this, including this quote:

> If you distribute your extension using the Chrome Web Store, the homepage URL defaults to the extension's own page.

I believe that it's either a bug that those are sent out to your server instead, or a feature I haven't seen documented anywhere to let *you* track those instead. Note that those are just beacons sent from analytics code; you don't need to serve content on them.

In any case, it's worth reporting, either on the [bugtracker](https://crbug.com/new) or via the exceptionally well-hidden [developer support form](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/).